# How check existence of a char and then do a mathematical function if it is true?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data of electrical components such as R1,R2,C1,T1,... If it's R then multiply its price to a number.How can I do it in excel with formula?

Comment: Please read this [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
=if(iferror(find("R*",A1,1),0)>0,B1*C1,"")
```

Assumed A1 has the component R1 etc, B1 is the price and C1 is the number.

Not tested as I am on the ´phone, but will do.